# Select only rows if its value in a particular column is less than the value in the other column

Tags: select, r, rows

I am using R and need to select rows with aged (age of death) less than or equal to laclen (lactation length). I am trying to create a new data frame to only include rows/ids whereby the value of column'aged' is less than its corresponding 'laclength' value.

```
df:
 id1   id2    laclen    aged
9830  64526    26       6 
7609  64547    28       0 
9925  64551     3       0 
9922  64551     3       5 
9916  64551     3       8 
9917  64551     3       8 
9914  64551     3       2
```

the new data frame should look like this:

```
dfnew:
id1   id2    laclen    aged
9830  64526    26       6 
7609  64547    28       0 
9925  64551     3       0 
9914  64551     3       2
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Bazon

Comment: Please give more details about your need.

Comment: Hi Karthik,

I am trying to create a new data frame to only include rows/ids whereby the value of column'aged' is less than the value of column 'laclength'

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
df[df$aged <= df$laclen, ]
```

Should do the trick. The square brackets allow you to index based on a logical expression.

Comment: thanks, aL3xa! I will keep this one as well. I can see that its very similar to one wkmor1 sent earlier.

Comment: @aL3xa `attach` without `detach` could be dangerous... And I think that comma is misplaced.

Comment: @Marek, thanks for suggestions! I've added `detach` and placed comma after the right bracket, so it goes like this: `attach(df); newdf <- df[which(aged <= laclen), ]; detach(df)`

Comment: @aL3xa You could also use `with` - `newdf <- df[with(df,which(aged <= laclen)), ]` instead of `attach/detach`.

Comment: I get the error:`Error in Ops.factor(value, productcode) :   level sets of factors are different`, had to set the levels on those fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594981/getting-the-error-level-sets-of-factors-are-different-when-running-a-for-loop

Comment: This solution returns NA lines when the criteria are not met, the @Jonathan Chang answer worked best for me

Answer (score 62):

You can also do

```
subset(df, aged <= laclen)
```

Comment: nice one, makes code neater according to me, pity `R CMD check` does not recognize the fields used in the test as legitimate variables. it emits a `NOTE` "no visible binding for global variable".

Comment: `subset()` has some serious problems, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset

Answer (score 14):

If you use `dplyr` package you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, aged <= laclen)
```