# select rows with unidentical column values using R

Tags: select, r, rows

I need to create a new data frame that excludes dams that appear in "dam1" and
"dam2" columns on the same fosdate (fostering date). I tried `df <- df[df$dam1!=df$dam2,]` but did not work. Dam1 and dam2 are factors which are the id's of mothers.

my df:

```
fosdate      dam1     dam2
8/09/2009    2Z523    2Z523
30/10/2009   1W509    5C080
30/10/2009   1W509    5C640
30/10/2009   1W509    1W509
1/10/2009    1W311    63927
```

The new data frame that I need to get is:
dfnew:

```
fosdate      dam1     dam2
30/10/2009   1W509    5C080
30/10/2009   1W509    5C640
1/10/2009    1W311    63927
```

Would appreciate any help!

Bazon

Comment: Hey Bazon, what's with the two different accounts withthe same user name asking effectively duplicate questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863316/selecting-rows-with-unidentical-values-appearing-in-two-different-columns-in-r

Comment: You may want to clarify what language/framework this question is for, as it stands, the question is pretty ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that dam1 and dam2 are factors each with a different number of levels.  To get around this you need to convert the factors to "characters" to do that comparison.

```
dfnew <-df[as.character(df$dam1) != as.character(df$dam2), ]
```

Comment: Brian, thanks alot! that did the trick. i understand it better with the explanation you provide!

Comment: As states in help to `factor` comparisons works for factor & character, so `df[as.character(df$dam1) != df$dam2, ]` works as well. You may use `subset`: `subset(df, as.character(dam1) != dam2)`.

Comment: thanks marek! its good to know various ways of approaching a problem. it sure builds confidence!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you imported the data, df$dam1 and df$dam2 became factors

You can check this with

```
is.factor(df$dam1)
```

If this is the TRUE, then try something like

```
df[as.character(df$dam1) != as.character(df$dam2),]
```

Comment: Correct, except != instead of ==.

Comment: sameer,
thanks to you too! thats right - "!=" instead of "=="

Answer (score -1):

Wild guess based on the idea that you might be using R (since your other questions are about R). Note that I don't know R, I'm just putting 2 and 2 together from the other questions and answers given.

Try

```
df <- df[df$dam1 != df$dam2,]
```

i.e. specifiy df$ explicitly on both sides of the comparison clause.

Comment: i have just edited the question above. the syntax used was
df <-df[df$dam1!=df$dam2,]. the message i got was: Error in Ops.factor(fosdetail2$sow, fosdetail2$recipsow) : 
  level sets of factors are different. i am new to R and trying to claw my way through!

Comment: why the two accounts? i came to know this helpful site last weak and so i joined. i somehow logged out and could not log in again to my account and really wanted to get this question across - so created another account.

Comment: Did you try the subset way of doing it as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854625/select-only-rows-if-its-value-in-a-particular-column-is-less-than-its-value-in-th/2854856#2854856  ?

Comment: Sheesh, don't you hate it when someone votes down your answer which is only no longer relevant because the question was edited in response to your answer?

Comment: i am so sorry whybird! it was my mistake that the first syntax appeared in my initial question (before you pointed out the correction). i sincerely apologise for my mistake!