# select only rows if its value in a particular column is more than 5 times its value in the other colum

Tags: r

I have started to learn the the R very recently so forgive me if it's a novice question for someone. I want to extract the row from column "Bladder" which value is more than 5 times higher in compare to other column.

```
gene     Adrenal    Amygdala    Bladder BoneMarrow
1007_s_at   10.46973369 11.26483864 100.43303178    9.907426976
1053_at 6.446570421 6.462840464 6.570665594 7.068326351
117_at  8.018137441 7.738652705 7.604989675 8.38937883
121_at  10.78168853 10.3223056  10.38043102 10.73936285
1255_g_at   5.625038847 6.132930765 5.526885199 5.448521716
1294_at 8.37142904  8.1019947   8.549260758 8.697436419
1316_at 6.237386633 6.429011484 6.083330287 6.295933456
1320_at 6.206410651 6.139873183 6.328348899 6.251521738
1405_i_at   6.588370219 5.949622255 7.420451672 8.823058974
```

Expected result

```
gene     Adrenal    Amygdala    Bladder BoneMarrow
1007_s_at   10.46973369 11.26483864 100.43303178    9.907426976
```

I got this answer useful but I don't know how to apply for multiple columns
[select only rows if its value in a particular column is less than its value in the other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854625/select-only-rows-if-its-value-in-a-particular-column-is-less-than-its-value-in-t)

Thanks.

Comment: Given the data frame above, can you post the expected result?

Comment: "more than 5 times higher in compare to other column". That statement is quite ambiguous. 5x higher than _any_ other column or than _all_ other columns?

Comment: `dplyr::filter(your_data, Blatter > 5*(column_you_are_talking_about))`. If you have multiple conditions just add multiple arguments to filter to include those conditions. e.g., . `Blatter > 5*other_column_you_are_talking_about`

Comment: As is, your posted data has no occurrence of examples for which Bladder is greater than 5 times any or all the other columns. Please fix that and then post expected results. Also, you may want to name that first column.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I just updated the question

Comment: @Axeman I mean 5x higher than all other columns. Thanks

Comment: @pali: sorry, but do you mean to change that 100.46973369 value to Bladder instead of Adrenal? Otherwise, your condition is to return rows in which any column other than Bladder is greater than 5 * Bladder.

Comment: @aichao Thanks for catching it. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

You want to perform a subset of your data based on your condition. Here, I assume your data is in a data frame named `df`:

```
df[df$Bladder > apply(5 * subset(df, select=-c(gene, Bladder)), 1, max),]
```

This will select the rows of `df` for which the `Bladder` column is more than 5 times the max of the other columns. We select all columns other than `Bladder` and `gene` using the `subset` command, and we compute the row-wise `max` using `apply` with the `MARGIN` set to `1` (i.e., the first margin or rows).

Using the updated data in your post, we get:

```
##       gene  Adrenal Amygdala  Bladder BoneMarrow
##1 1007_s_at 10.43303 11.26484 100.4697   9.907427
```

The data is:

```
df <- structure(list(gene = structure(1:9, .Label = c("1007_s_at", 
"1053_at", "117_at", "121_at", "1255_g_at", "1294_at", "1316_at", 
"1320_at", "1405_i_at"), class = "factor"), Adrenal = c(10.43303178, 
6.446570421, 8.018137441, 10.78168853, 5.625038847, 8.37142904, 
6.237386633, 6.206410651, 6.588370219), Amygdala = c(11.26483864, 
6.462840464, 7.738652705, 10.3223056, 6.132930765, 8.1019947, 
6.429011484, 6.139873183, 5.949622255), Bladder = c(100.46973369, 
6.570665594, 7.604989675, 10.38043102, 5.526885199, 8.549260758, 
6.083330287, 6.328348899, 7.420451672), BoneMarrow = c(9.907426976, 
7.068326351, 8.38937883, 10.73936285, 5.448521716, 8.697436419, 
6.295933456, 6.251521738, 8.823058974)), .Names = c("gene", "Adrenal", 
"Amygdala", "Bladder", "BoneMarrow"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly. Can you explain this part of your answer please "we compute the row-wise max using apply with the MARGIN set to 1 (i.e., the first margin or rows)"

Comment: @pali: see `?apply`. Basically, `apply` applies a function along a dimension (refer in the docs as margin) of a multi-dimensional array or matrix. Here, the function is `max` and we want to apply it across `rows` (first margin or dimension) of the data frame (excluding the `gene` and `Bladder` columns).

Answer (score 0):

This question was not asked terribly well, so my answer may not be quite what you are expecting, but I think what you're trying to get at is important and simple enough. My example makes use of the `dplyer` library which simplifies the filtering and selection of values from the data frame. Please note that I changed the value of *BoneMarrow* in the first row so that *Bladder* would be more than five times larger.

Most of the code is just to set up the example so that it is reproducible; the first and last lines are the actual answer to the question.

```
library(dplyr)

txt=
"gene,Adrenal,Amygdala,Bladder,BoneMarrow
1007_s_at,100.46973369,11.26483864,10.43303178,1.907426976
1053_at,6.446570421,6.462840464,6.570665594,7.068326351
117_at,8.018137441,7.738652705,7.604989675,8.38937883
121_at,10.78168853,10.3223056,10.38043102,10.73936285
1255_g_at,5.625038847,6.132930765,5.526885199,5.448521716
1294_at,8.37142904,8.1019947,8.549260758,8.697436419
1316_at,6.237386633,6.429011484,6.083330287,6.295933456
1320_at,6.206410651,6.139873183,6.328348899,6.251521738
1405_i_at,6.588370219,5.949622255,7.420451672,8.823058974"

df = read.table(textConnection(txt), header=TRUE, sep=',')

filter(df, Bladder >= BoneMarrow * 5) %>% select(Bladder)
```

Comment: sorry for not being very clear in my question. I got this error when I run your code "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Bladder' not found
". It appears that in your code it is assumed that value in Bladder will be more than 5 times than BoneMarrow but my assumption is that value in Bladder should be 5 time more than another column. Thanks though.

Comment: That error was because I did something silly and used-tab delimiters in my data set, which is just begging for issues when someone copy-pastes it. I changed it to csv so hopefully it parses for you now.

Comment: When you say "value in Bladder should be 5 time more than another column", do you mean that Bladder should be 5 times more than *any* other column, or *every* other column?

Comment: I mean it should be 5 times more than every other column. Sorry for not being so clear.